# Google Spreadsheets

Tags: php

How to list all "pages" of the specific Sheets?

Example my code:

```
$spreadsheetId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxeZCs9CSbDwyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'; (static)
$planilha_atual = "EXAMPLE1"; (static)

$response1 = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $planilha_atual."!B68:C71");
```

I need to list all "pages" (`$planilha_atual`) from this Sheet (`$planilha_atual`).

List: `EXAMPLE1`, `EXAMPLE2`, `EXAMPLE3` from this ID: `$spreadsheetId`